# Javascript Windows Framework

Tags: frameworks, javascript, rich-internet-application

Sometimes I see web based software that is designed using some slick javascript windows which try to emulate the Windows desktop experience (draggable windows and a start menu).

Are there any free frameworks like this available?

Comment: I won't put this in as an answer, because it's ooooooooold (really old), but I wrote something like this, and it's available at http://www.ryankinal.com/javascript/SquishyUI.php - It likely needs updating, and it's pretty rough, but it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like [ExtJs](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/)?. Here are some demos

[Desktop like webpage](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/desktop/desktop.html)

[Feed viewer](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/feed-viewer/view.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would check out jQuery UI

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: I have extensive experience with this. I'm looking for something more specific to giving that windows feel to a webpage. UI does rock, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to have a look at http://qooxdoo.org/demo - I don't have experience with it, but it looks quite capable.